# Can't capture info from omxplayer

Tags: omxplayer

When I do this (to capture info into a `file.txt`):

```
$ omxplayer -i sounds/Maniacal_Witches_Laugh-SoundBible.com-262127569.mp3 > file.txt
Input #0, mp3, from 'sounds/Maniacal_Witches_Laugh-SoundBible.com-262127569.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Maniacal Witches Laugh
    artist          : Maniacal Witches Laugh
    album           : Maniacal Witches Laugh
    genre           : Blues
  Duration: 00:00:02.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 83 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 82 kb/s
have a nice day ;)
```

...in the file I only get this:

```
$ cat file.txt 
have a nice day ;)
```

How can I get the whole output of the -i command into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

">" only captures stdout, to capture the errout stream as well you need "2>&1"

```
 omxplayer -i sounds/Maniacal_Witches_Laugh-SoundBible.com-262127569.mp3 >file.txt 2>&1
```

or

```
omxplayer -i sounds/Maniacal_Witches_Laugh-SoundBible.com-262127569.mp3 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

Comment: ? There is no error. The output in my question is stdout (hence `2>&1` redirects nothing).

Comment: if it is not captured by ">" then by definition it is not stdout and the only other standard output stream is stderr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file

Comment: The correct format is `...mp3 > file.txt 2>&1` or just `...mp3 2>&1 | <process_it_inline>`. Correct your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: sorry, should have read what I wrote before trying to defend it. answer updated.

Comment: Np. Important thing is: problem solved.